# Bash IF/ELIF statements

Tags: linux, bash

So I am learning bash and wanted to make a script to 'automate' a collection of kali tools. Basically I do not understand why the if statement code is being triggered regardless if condition is true or false.

```
#!/bin/bash
#requires root or sudo priv

#check for a successful ping

target_ip=$1
nmap_opt = " "
#nmap options variables --
nmap_os="-O"
nmap_version="-sV"
nmap_udp="-sU"
nmap_stealth="-sS"
nmap_aggr="-A"
nmap_option_input_temp=""
ping $target_ip -c 5
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "successful ping on" $target_ip 
else
        echo "ping unsuccessful, check VPN connection or host may be down"
        exit 1
fi

read -p "enter pathway for nmap output: " nmap_file
read -p "detect os? (y/n) " nmap_option_input_temp

#add loops for y/n user input
if [[ ${nmap_option_input_temp} -eq "y" ]];
         then
                nmap_opt="${nmap_opt} ${nmap_os}"

elif [[ ${nmap_option_input_temp} -eq "n" ]];
         then
                nmap_opt=$nmap_opt
else
        echo "invalid option"  
fi

read -p "detect version? (y/n) " nmap_option_input_temp
#add loops for y/n user input
if [[ ${nmap_option_input_temp} -eq "y" ]];
                 then
                        nmap_opt="${nmap_opt} ${nmap_version}"

elif [[ ${nmap_option_input_temp} -eq "n" ]];
                 then
                        nmap_opt=$nmap_opt
else
        echo "invalid option"  
fi


echo "nmap selected option/s:" $nmap_opt
echo $nmap_option_input_temp
#starting nmap..
sudo nmap $nmap_opt -oN $nmap_file $target_ip
```

this is the nmap_opt variable echo out even when both inputs are 'n'

```
nmap selected option/s: -O -sV
```

Let me know if there is anything I missed in the explanation!

Comment: Another example of why you should never use `[[`.  `-eq` is doing integer comparisons.  Strings are being evaluated as 0.  `[[` is discarding the error message that you would get from `[`

Answer (score 0):

`-eq` is for integer comparisons.  Use `==`:

```
if [[ "${nmap_option_input_temp}" == y ]];
```

And fix your quotes.  Fixed strings like `y` don't need to be quoted.  Inside `[[`, variables don't need to be quoted, but IMO you should quote them anyway for consistency.

This error would be more easily spotted if you used the more conventional:

```
if [ "${nmap_option_input_temp}" -eq y ];  # Still incorrect!!
```

since you would get a nice error message.

Note that the fix with `[` is slightly different, and you should use a single `=`:

```
if [ "${nmap_option_input_temp}" = y ];
```

The `==` operator is a bashism which does not really add any value.  But really, you should not be using `if/elif` at all here.  This is the perfect place for a `case` statement:

```
case "${nmap_option_input_temp}" in
y) nmap_opt="${nmap_opt} ${nmap_os}";;
n) ;;
*) echo "invalid option" >&2 ;; 
esac
```